# NSString stringWithFormat is slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, nsstring

In Objective-C, the method `stringWithFormat:` seems to be extremely slow and is actually a large bottleneck in one of our apps (we used the profiler to find that out).
Is there a way to optimise it or use some faster C code?

Comment: How could we know without seeing any of your code?

Comment: I am not talking about a specific code. i am talking about the line [NSString stringWithFormat]

Comment: How do you identify it as bottle neck of your app?

Comment: What do you mean by 'bottleneck'? Does it consume too much CPU? Does it make UI slow? Maybe you could relocate those calls away from main thread.

Comment: Interpreting a format string is inherently slow.  If you can used other techniques, and performance is an issue, then go ahead.  (And, for crying out loud, don't use things like `myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", "ABC"];` as I've seen many times here.  It's totally wasted motion!)

Comment: You don't use retarded code like `NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherString];` do you?  I've seen plenty of examples of that on stackoverflow...

Comment: @HotLicks great minds...

Comment: (Give us two or three examples of your use of stringWithFormat.)

Comment: What do you mean by "use some faster C code"? Also, your question is nearly impossible to answer without code. We need to see how you are using stringWithFormat.

Comment: I simply use it for string concatanation

Comment: @DrummerB your comment in most cases would be reasonable, but it seems that NSString stringWithFormat is *always* very slow, irrespective of the circumstances, which makes the question valid. With the help of this question, I did some experiments, and it's *always* sped up considerably by using sprintf. If you're doing any kind of rendering using strings for texture names, render path dictionaries, etc ...  a 500% improvement in string concatenation speed (5x faster is typical when using sprintf) is a big thing :).

Answer (score 8):

Yes
use `sprintf` in c http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/
after that push the char* in a NSString with `[NSString stringWithUTF8:];`

example:

```
char cString[255];
sprintf (cString, "%d", 36);
NSString* OCstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:cString];
```

Comment: Looking for a general-purpose drop-in replacement for stringWithFormat... harder than it looks!

Comment: @JMBise Do i need to release the char array afterwards ?

Comment: @Danpe No, you don't need to release the char array, because it's not a pointer. It will be automatically released at the end of the function(if it is inside a function) or after each run of the loop(if it is inside in loop)

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing extensive string manipulations and operations - it sounds like you might well be doing so, and `NSString` really is becoming a bottleneck for your app, I recommend trying to use C++ for your string needs rather then C.

Apple admits that while `NSString` is great, it is top level, in fact, to make their autocorrect algorithm's for iOS they ran into a similar problem, `NSString` was too slow to compute and compare so many things. They then switched to C++ and got all the performance they needed.

Just a suggestion. You should definitely put up some code, I am surprised this is happening to you unless you're doing some awesome new feature !

Comment: Source for the middle paragraph?

Comment: It was in a WWDC 2012 video. I'm going to rack my brains for which one it was now. TBC.

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested in watching that video if you remember which one it was.

Comment: Okay got it: Session 212 Basics + Habits: Building Your Software To Last - at 13 minutes. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=212#212