# decoding a HUGE NSString, running out of memory

Tags: ios, xml, memory-management, base64, nsdata

I'm looking for ideas on how to improve a process of decoding a 40+MB NSString with base64 encoding and saving it to a file while being able to fit the process into iPad 1's 256 MB of RAM

I get the NSString from NSXMLParser:

```
id pointerToString;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"myElement"]) 
    {
    pointerToString = [string retain];
}
}
```

Then I use the pointerToString in a callback:

```
[handler performSelector: action withObject: pointerToString];
```

In the callback (id value is the pointerToString). I initialize NSData with the pointerToString while decoding it with base64 encoding.

```
^(id value)
{
    if ( [[value class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]] ) 
    {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:value];
    [data writeToFile:file.path atomically:YES];
}
}
```

the iPad 1 device runs out of memory and gets killed by the iOS when the memory allocation reaches around 130MB after or during the NSData call.

I have determined that in order to process the 40+MB NSString this way, I'd need about 180+MB of RAM (this is what the maximum memory allocation is on iPad 2 & 3, where the process works because of more RAM)

Any ideas/tips ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know, but an excellent question. However, I would like to know why you have an NSString that big?

Comment: Modify the base64 encoding to decode the characters to a file as you receive them from the parser.

Comment: Keyword: "streaming" (the entire process, this also involves removing the full in-memory usage of `NSData`)

Comment: It appears you are actually trying to **decode** the base64 string.

Comment: You commonly have around 140mb RAM free at max on the iPad1 - often less. And yes, I mixed that up - the iPad 1 does have 256mb shared RAM. Plenty of which is used by the OS and the screen.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm finding myself. I can get to ~130MB, but obviously that depends on what else is going on on the iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

When dealing with a file of this size, you probably do not want to load the entire multi-megabyte file in memory at one time, neither the huge input file nor the almost-as-huge output file. You should be parsing this in a streaming fashion, decoding the data in your `foundCharacters` as you go along, not holding any significant portions in memory.

The traditional techniques, though, may hold your entire XML file memory in three phases of the process:

1. As you download the XML file from the server;
2. As the XML parser parses that file; and
3. As you do the Base64-decode of the file.

The trick is to employ a streaming technique, that does these three processes at once, for small chunks of the single, large XML file. Bottom line, as you're downloading the entire 50mb file, grab a few kb, parse the XML, and if you're parsing the Base64-encoded field, perform the Base64-decode for that few kb, and the proceed to the next chunk of data.

For an example of this (at least the streaming XML downloading-and-parsing, not including the Base64-decoding), please see Apple's [XMLPerformance sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008094). You'll see that it will demonstrate two XML parsers, the `NSXMLParser` that we're all familiar with, as well as the less familiar `LibXML` parser. The issue with `NSXMLParser` is that, left to it's own devices, will load the entire XML file in memory before it starts parsing, even if you use `initWithContentsOfURL`.

In my previous answer, I mistakenly claimed that by using `initWithContentsOfURL`, the `NSXMLParser` would parse the URL's contents in nice little packets as they were being downloaded. The `foundCharacters` method of `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol seems so analogous to the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method, `didReceiveData`, that I was sure that `NSXMLParser` was going to handle the stream just like `NSURLConnection` does, namely returning information as the download was in progress. Sadly, it doesn't.

By using `LibXML`, though, like the Apple XMLPerformance sample project, you can actually use the `NSURLConnection` ability of streaming, and thus parse the XML on the fly.

I have created a little [test project](https://github.com/robertmryan/iOS-XML-Streaming-w-Base64-Decode), but I might suggest that you go through Apple's XMLPerformance sample project in some detail. But in my experiment, a 56mb XML file consumed well over 100mb when parsing and converting via `NSXMLParser` but only consumed 2mb when using `LibXML2`.

---

In your comments, you describe the desire to download the Base64-encoded data to a file and then decode that. That approach seems a lot less efficient, but certainly could work. By the way, on that initial download, you have the same memory problem (that I solve above). I urge you to make sure that your initial download of the Base64-encoded data does not blithely load it into RAM like most routines do. You want to, assuming you're using `NSURLConnection`, write the data to the `NSOutputStream` as you receive the data in `didReceiveData`, not hold it in RAM.

See the `didReceiveResponse` in AdvancedGetController.m of Apple's [AdvancedURLConnections example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009558) for an example of how to write a file as it's being received, rather than typical patterns of adding it to a `NSMutableData` (because most of these routines just assume you're dealing with a reasonably sized file). (Ignore all the stuff in that AdvancedURLConnections sample about authentication and the like, but focus on understanding how it's writing to the `NSOutputStream` as it goes.) This technique will address the first of the three problems listed at the top of this answer, but not the latter two. For that, you'll have to contemplate using `LibXML2` as illustrated in Apple's XMLPerformance sample project, or other similar techniques.

Comment: thank you for the fantastic writeup! unfortunately, I have no influence on the back-end setup. I get a single HUGE element in foundCharacters and I have to deal with that. So at the moment I'm trying to come up with a solution that would save the encoded NSString into the file system and then I'd read it back (in parts) in the callback, feed the parts through the base64 decoder, reassemble it into a decoded NSString and then save it to the file system again. I will leave my question unanswered for a bit and then accept yours if nothing more closely matching my scenario comes my way.

Comment: thanks Rob. I see you know a lot about this stuff. I appreciate the effort and I'm going to look to implementing your suggestions.

Comment: If you want to discuss further, we should move this to chat.

Comment: wow. what a difference the streaming makes. from ~190MB down to ~84MB of memory usage for ... and now working on iPad 1. Thank you Rob!

Comment: yeah, I figured there must be room for improvement. I am currenty using NSInputStream *inputStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:self.fileIncomingData]; and then xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithStream:inputStream];

Comment: @radvan72 I've significantly altered my answer with references to `LibXML2` given that `NSXMLParser` doesn't really lend itself to streaming. `LibXML2` had a much smaller footprint when used in conjunction with `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

is probably not receiving all the data at once.
 Doc is saying

"*Sent by a parser object to provide its delegate with a string representing all or part of the characters of the current element.*"

So it is called multiple times. 
It looks like you are trying to write the whole string at once (sorry if I am wrong).
So you could append the received data to the file by doing the following:

You can use a combination of

```
-writeData:
```

and

```
-seekToEndOfFile
```

methods from NSFileHandle class for writing NSData to the end of a file.

**But be carefull** with your base64 encoding on partial data receivment!

Comment: Hmm okay, if you are really getting all the data at once I would indeed try to split the whole string into smaller parts and write them to file (not all at once for sure). Your could consider doing this on a background thread to avoid blocking the main thread. I do not know the perfect performance, but you could expirence it a bit. For example starting with 1000 characters... But again, check your base64 endocing to work proberly due to the splits!

Comment: 1.000 Characters are a bad example probably because of the base 64 encoding of 24 bit blocks. Try using a character amount which can be divided by 3 for example (using utf-8 strings)

Comment: @Alexander - I think the boundary for the Base64 encoded file is every 4 bytes. I think you're confusing this with the boundary on the decoded file, which is every 3 bytes. Regardless, I would not advise changing the XML to break the file up in multiple bits, but rather have the Base64-decode process decode the stream on the fly, writing it to persistent storage as it goes along. And, if radvan72 has any control over the XML, the idea fix would be to avoid Base64 encoding altogether (per the comments near the end of my answer).

Comment: @Rob yes you are right! I was talking about having a plain string and encoding it to base64. That's why I talked about the 3 byte boundary. The encoded file itself for sure does have a boundary every 4 bytes