# iOS key chain persistence and performance

Tags: ios, keychain

In our applications we use keychain extensively to communicate with other application.
I have a question related to key chain usage and limitations.

Key chain can store very long string, same as max length of NSString.
What are the performance implications of storing huge data (GB's of data) in key chain?

Does iOS deletes key chain files during low memory conditions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your memory question, take a look at this previous post:

[decoding a HUGE NSString, running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691787/decoding-a-huge-nsstring-running-out-of-memory)

Regarding your performance issue, take a look at this previous answer:

[NSString stringWithFormat is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568822/nsstring-stringwithformat-is-slow)

Comment: This is a question about **keychain** persistence and performance. NSString was only mentioned in regards to the size limit.

Comment: @sup Why don't you give a better answer instead of teaching interpretations. I think this answer is helpful, considering no-one else has responded.